# What is the best way for me to print out a 2d array in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm fairly new to coding, so this may seem like a bit of a silly question, however I am trying to print a 2d array grid and I'm not sure how I am supposed to do it. This is my code so far:

```
colA = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
colB = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
colC = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
colD = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
colE = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " "]

grid = [colA, colB, colC, colD, colE]

print("|"+[4,0]+"|"+[4,1]+"|"+[4,2]+"|"+[4,3]+"|"+[4,4]+"|")
print("|"+[3,0]+"|"+[3,1]+"|"+[3,2]+"|"+[3,3]+"|"+[3,4]+"|")
print("|"+[2,0]+"|"+[2,1]+"|"+[2,2]+"|"+[2,3]+"|"+[2,4]+"|")
print("|"+[1,0]+"|"+[1,1]+"|"+[1,2]+"|"+[1,3]+"|"+[1,4]+"|")
print("|"+[0,0]+"|"+[0,1]+"|"+[0,2]+"|"+[0,3]+"|"+[0,4]+"|")
```

It's basic, I know, but I just don't get it. When I try to print the grid, it comes up with this error message:

```
print("|"+[4,0]+"|"+[4,1]+"|"+[4,2]+"|"+[4,3]+"|"+[4,4]+"|")
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

What does this error message mean? Can I convert the 2d arrays into the strings they are in their respective lists without the console displaying something like: |[0,0]|[0,1]|[0,2]| etc.

Comment: What do you expect `"|" + [4,0]` to evaluate to? Also, you may find [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) helpful, e.g. `'|'.join(colA) == " | | | | | "`.

Comment: I expect it will become an empty space as in: |   |   |   |   |   , so I can replace the variables later

Comment: `[4, 0]` is a list. Do you mean to index the list `grid`, e.g. `grid[4][0]`?

Comment: Just tried that, but it gave me this:  print("|"+grid[4,0]+"|"+grid[4,1]+"|"+grid[4,2]+"|"+grid[4,3]+"|"+grid[4,4]+"|")
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: The `TypeError` you received is correct. You are attempting to index `grid` with a tuple, namely `(4,0)`. Consider reading the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) covering lists for the basic syntax of indexing and using nexted lists.

Comment: Ok I got it working now thanks man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple code snippet to display a 2-D matrix in a 'pretty' way:

```
arr = [[1,2,'3'], [4,5,'trampoline'], ['rf', 'th', 8.7]]
print("\n".join(str(row) for row in arr))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, '3']
[4, 5, 'trampoline']
['rf', 'th', 8.7]
```

It's essentially doing the following - 
`[1, 2, '3'] + "\n" + [4, 5, 'trampoline'] + "\n" + ['rf', 'th', 8.7]`

if you execute the above line, you'll get a similar error to the one you mentioned.
`(TypeError: must be str, not list)`

Notice the `str(row)` in the code. By typecasting the list to a string, I am ensuring that concatenation happens between two string types only.